# Create Download URL String which have header set in JAVA

Tags: java, url, header

I have one URL which points to file on server, this file is saved on server with name "ABC.txt". This url is used as download link on UI, when user clicks for download, file gets downloaded with name "ABC.txt". 
But while downloading I want to download it with different name, For example, each download should add timestamp to file name "ABC_12-sep-2013.txt" or "ABC-12312312312.txt" by setting filename in content-disposition.

I am trying to find way to do this in Java Code.

Please provide some pointers on this.

Comment: Does your server keep this file or is it external server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set appropriate content type:

```
res.setContentType(mimeType + "; name=" + name + "\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=" + name + "\n\n");
```

http://home-1.worldonline.nl/~bmc88/java/sbook/088.html